# When does $p(x^k)$ have irreducible factor $(x-\sqrt[k]{x_1})(x-\sqrt[k]{x_2})\cdots(x-\sqrt[k]{x_n})$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

Suppose that $p(x)=(x-x_1)(x-x_2)\cdots(x-x_n)$ is a monic irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}$. When does $p(x^k), k\geq1$ have irreducible factor $(x-\sqrt[k]{x_1})(x-\sqrt[k]{x_2})\cdots(x-\sqrt[k]{x_n})$?

For example $p(x)=x^3-6x^2+5x-1$ has roots $x_1=5.0492..., x_2=0.643104..., x_3=0.307979...$ and $p(x^2)=(x^3-2x^2-x+1)(x^3+2x^2-x-1)$ where $x^3-2x^2-x+1=(x-\sqrt[3]{x_1})(x-\sqrt[3]{x_2})(x-\sqrt[3]{x_3})$.

Comment: If I've understood your question correctly: always, if we consider roots over $\mathbb{C}$. The key is that $x^k - x_i = (x - \sqrt[k]{x_i}) (x - \zeta \sqrt[k]{x_i}) \cdots (x - \zeta^{k-1}\sqrt[k]{x_i})$ where $\zeta$ is a primitive $k^\text{th}$ root of unity and $\sqrt[k]{x_i}$ is any $k^\text{th}$ root of $x_i$.

Comment: @André3000 sorry I meant when is $(x-\sqrt[k]{x_1})(x-\sqrt[k]{x_2})\cdots(x-\sqrt[k]{x_n})$ ian irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}$. If $p(x)=x^2-4x+2=(x-2-\sqrt{2})(x-2+\sqrt{2})$, then $p(x^2)=x^6-4x^2+2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$ by Eisenstein's criterion. Thus $(x-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}})(x-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}})$ is not a polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}$